# Retrieve an NSMutableArray which is in a method from another method of same class

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone i have a small doubt that is I have a method in a class that is below

```
-(void)bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue:(NSMutableArray *)receivedBookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue{
    NSLog(@"receivedBookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue is %@",receivedBookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue);
    bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue = receivedBookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue;
    NSLog(@"bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue is %@",bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue);
}
```

here bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue is an NSMutableArray it contains some data in it.I want to retrieve this array with that data in another method in same class how it is possible.If anybody know this please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a method that returns the `NSMutableArray`:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue:(NSMutableArray *)receivedBookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue{
    NSLog(@"receivedBookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue is %@",receivedBookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue);
    bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:receivedBookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue];
    NSLog(@"bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue is %@",bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue);
    return bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue;
}
```

Now you can call this method from the method where you want to retrive the `NSMutableArray`!!

All the best!!!