# Access NSMutablearray from anotherclass

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve an NSMutableArray which is in a method from another method of same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465286/retrieve-an-nsmutablearray-which-is-in-a-method-from-another-method-of-same-clas)

I am new to iphone i have a small doubt that is I have an NSMutableArray which is in the class 
DownloadManager.m like below

```
- (void) queueDownload: (Download*) download
{
    [bookTitlesWhichAreInDownloadQueue addObject:download.title_];
    NSLog(@"bookTitlesWhichAreInDownloadQueue is %@",bookTitlesWhichAreInDownloadQueue);
}
```

In the above method `bookTitlesWhichAreInDownloadQueue` is an NSMutableArray

I want to access this array in the method which is in another class(BiblePlayerViewController.m) that is the below method

```
-(void)showingAlertViewWhenBookIsNotDownloaded {
 NSLog(@"bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue1 is %d",[bookNamesWhichAreInDownloadedQueue count]);
}
```

how it is possible if any body know this please help me...

Comment: 3rd question with same content in 20 mins ...

Comment: You should remove the questions as you have already posted a couple like this before. You can always get the required answer, no need to exert extra effort like this. It might waste everyone's time.

Comment: I told you he posts every 20 mins. hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add property of NSMutableArray in .h class like this

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *yourarray;
```

and synthesize the array in .m class

```
@synthesize yourarray;
```

this set the getter and setter.